# NSManagedObject exception “this class is not key value coding-compliant” and crashes the app in ios 6 but works for ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I having an issue where my application crashes with the following exception:

### ABC[1936:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_NSObjectID_48_0 0xb63e310> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'

The strange issue with this exception is that it does not occur when using iOS5. Please see the code where the exception takes place below:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

if ((self.sectionInfoArray == nil) ||
    ([self.sectionInfoArray count] != [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]))
{
    NSMutableArray *infoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Tour *tour in self.tours)
    {
        SectionInfo *sectionInfo = [[SectionInfo alloc] init];
        sectionInfo.tour = tour;
        sectionInfo.open = NO;

        NSLog(@"Tour Details Count %@", [[tour tourDetails] objectAtIndex:0]);

        NSNumber *defaultRowHeight = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT];
        NSInteger countOfQuotations = [[sectionInfo.tour tourDetails] count];

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countOfQuotations; i++)
        {
            [sectionInfo insertObject:defaultRowHeight inRowHeightsAtIndex:i];
        }

        [infoArray addObject:sectionInfo];
    }

    self.sectionInfoArray = infoArray;
}
```

}

Would this exception be being caused because due to me having a Fetched Property defined within the class Tour that gets an array of TourDetail classes. Please see the implementation code for both classes below:

```
    #import "Tour.h"
#import "TourDetail.h"

@implementation Tour

@dynamic background_url;
@dynamic id;
@dynamic summary;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic tour_tourdetail;

@dynamic tourDetails;

@end

#import "TourDetail.h"


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class TourDetail;

@interface Tour : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * background_url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * summary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TourDetail *tour_tourdetail;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tourDetails;

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface TourDetail : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * audiofile;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * detail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * lattitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * tour_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObject *tourdetail_tour;

@end



@implementation TourDetail

@dynamic audiofile;
@dynamic detail;
@dynamic id;
@dynamic lattitude;
@dynamic longitude;
@dynamic title;
@dynamic tour_id;
@dynamic tourdetail_tour;

@end
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. As I am at a loss as to how I can fix this.

Thanks,
Michael

UPDATE:

When I remove the Fetched Property the exception does not occur with iOS6. Please see the predicate I have configured below:

### Fetched Property tourDetails Predicate tour_id == $FETCH_SOURCE.id

Can you see anything I doing wrong with the setup of this predicate ? My goal is to use this so as I can return an Array of TourDetail objects for each tour_id that mathces the id column inside the Tour table.

UPDATE:

I have been able to diagnose that the exception is being thrown because of the Predicate as when I call both tables separately there is no exception raised. Can you see any issue with the predicate that I have created ?

Please see code below showing how I am retrieving the objects from the Core Data DB:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [DrivingToursContent setupStaticData];

    self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = HEADER_HEIGHT;
    _openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"custombackground.ptoung"]];

    self.managedObjectContext = [[BaseCoreDataController sharedInstance] newManagedObjectContext];

    [self loadRecordsFromCoreData];

    [self loadRecordsFromCoreDataForTourDetail];

    NSLog(@"Tour Detail array count: %d", [self.toursTest count]);

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)loadRecordsFromCoreData {
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self.managedObjectContext reset];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Tour class])];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"id" ascending:YES]]];
        self.tours = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    }];
}
```

UPDATE:

The root of the problem is definitely coming from the Predicate I have defined for the Fetched property but can you advise how I should write the predicate to link between the 2 tables. As when I write the predicate tour_id == 0 and directly reference an id I know exists the fetched property works correctly. But when I use $FETCH_SOURCE.id the key value coding exception is thrown. What property do you use to reference the the table you wish to link to ?

Really appreciate all your help with this.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Could you post the crash log and relevant class

Comment: Not nearly enough detail about what's actually happening. What key is at issue? What object/class? What are you doing when the error occurs?

Comment: You currently have three close votes on this question, because you haven't given enough detail. I've added in something from your comment on the answer, but you really need to paste in the _exact_ error message from your crash log.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue since when I started to use the RestKit to create contexts, instead of using Coredata Boilerplate. Did you find a solution? Are you using RestKit?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code, you are calling a method on a class that was deprecated in iOS6, hence the crash.

Comment: Hi Andrei

All thanks for getting back to me on this please see the example code below. Basically I have 2 tables within my Core Data db and I have setup one to have a Fetched property that will populate an array. 

The exception is thrown when I attempt to get the total count from the array I am populating using the Fetched Property. Please see the line where the exception is thrown below:

Comment: NSInteger countOfQuotations = [[sectionInfo.tour tourDetails] count];

SectionInfo holds the Tour object that contains an array of TourDetail objects. The exception is thrown cause the class Tour Detail is apparently not key value coding compliant even though this works in iOS5. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: **Not key value compliant for what?** If an object is not key-value compliant, the error tells you what key it's not compliant for.

Comment: Hi the object is not key value compliant for the key id that I have setup. But the same column id works on other tables. Have you ever experienced this ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the code you've posted for `viewWillAppear` that touches Core Data in any obvious way at all, which makes it kind of hard to guess what's going on. Some of those objects might be managed objects, but who knows which ones or how you created them?

However the error message does provide a huge clue:

```
[<_NSObjectID_48_0 0xb63e310> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.
```

The fact that this mentions `_NSObjectID_48_0` indicates that at some point you're using `NSManagedObjectID` instances when you're expecting `NSManagedObject` instances. `NSManagedObjectID` does not have a property named `id`, no matter what the entity looks like, so asking one for its `id` will produce a "not key value coding compliant" error.

As for why this would be happening, it's still impossible to say, since you haven't posted any code that gives any clues about how you are using Core Data.

It **might** be something to do with the predicate:

```
tour_id == $FETCH_SOURCE.id
```

If you constructed a fetch so that `$FETCH_SOURCE` is an `NSManagedObjectID`, this would be a problem. Maybe (and I can only guess) you're using it while asking for a result type of `NSManagedObjectIDResultType`.

Comment: Thanks Tom for getting back to me on this. I have added the code I am using to return the results from Core Data to the question above. The issue is very strange because it works with no issue in iOS5 but crashes with the key value exception in iOS6. Are you aware of any changes made to getting Fetched Properties in iOS6 ?

Answer (score 0):

> @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;

Isn't `id` a reserved word in Objective-C? Have you tried renaming this property to something else, to see if that is causing any conflicts?

Comment: Hi Amy I have tried changing the property to be tour_id but still get the same error with iOS 6 but works with iOS5. Have you ever experienced an issue like this by chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into your code, NSFetchRequest can set the returned result type,
e.g., NSManagedObject**ID**ResultType or NSManagedObjectResultType.

NSManagedObjectResultType is wanted, but NSManagedObjectIDResultType is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue when I use MagicalRecord, but have no issue when use Xcode generate CoreData source code.